# Trying to get JSON data from POSTGRESQL in Django in localhost

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql

I and my friends are doing a project and now it is time to merge our postgresql databases and I need to grab everything from mine and send it as a JSON file.

As a programming newbie, I do not wanna mess up my database since I have done it once and was wondering what would be the easiest way to grab everything from http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ as a JSON file.

I currently have the home page and the footer information created and can be controlled from the admin page and need those data.

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            sender_name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            sender_email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            message = "{0} has sent you a new message:\n\n{1}".format(sender_name, form.cleaned_data['message'])
            send_mail('New Enquiry', message, sender_email, ['warp.dev.group@gmail.com'])
            return HttpResponse('Thanks for contacting us!')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    context = {
        "homepage": HomePage.objects.filter(name="homepage").first(),
        "footer": Footer.objects.filter(name="footer").first(),
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, 'member/home.html', context)
```

```
class Footer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    contact_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    facebook = models.URLField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    twitter = models.URLField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    instagram = models.URLField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    footer_data = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    terms_and_conditions = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    faq = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


class HomePage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    main_visual = models.ImageField(default="default.jpg", upload_to="homepage_pics")
    top_content_header = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    top_content = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    featured_groups_header = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    featured_groups = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    seven_groups_header = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    seven_groups = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    about_us_header = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    about_us = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'
```

Thank you!
Onur

Comment: Just use requests. ```data = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/')```

Comment: hey thanks for your answer! I thought I am suppose to enter the postgreq shell first and use dump? where am I to enter this request? thank you!

Comment: Ah yeah, I thought you wanted it in your code. If you want to backup your database then yeah you need to use pg_dump from the shell. Depending on if your using a managed database or one installed locally this process will vary slightly.

Comment: This [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata)?

Comment: I have dumped the data but realized thats not what I needed. I have to have all the data from the admin page into a JSON file.